# Delete admin edit/delete links in users list wordpress admin

Tags: capabilities

Iam trying to disable the capability for and admin to edit or delete other admins in the WordPress users list.
How can I do that without plugin ? 
Thanks[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b30wV.png)

[image: bert74]

Comment: It would be easier to make a custom role that doesn't have `manage_users` capability, but has all the other capabilities the users need. That way you're not just disabling visible links and potentially allowing them to visit a URL to delete anyway, you're actually preventing them from that capability entirely.

Comment: I agree with above @WebElaine, you still have a low amount of admins so it should be easy to achieve.  https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_role/